# PHP preg_replace: MY_NEW_CLASS to My_New_Class

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've got a string in PHP, `MY_NEW_CLASS` and I want to convert it to `My_New_Class`.

Is this possible using preg_replace or should I explode the string on the underscore, strtolower it, ucfirst it, then implode it back together?

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: why you want to use regex ?,if isnt necessary use your method.

Comment: @Ahmad: It certainly is, however I don't think it's the best method. Why write 3/4 lines if something can be done in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` by itself can't really do it I'd think, but it's not hard with a callback:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\b|_)./',
                             function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[0]); },
                             strtolower($str));
```

Comment: This works just great! Thanks. Would you be able to explain exactly how it works, in particular the RegEx you have used?

Comment: The regex simply matches any character *preceeded by a word boundary (like the beginning of the string) or a `_`*.

Comment: How come it only returns the first character? For example, the `m` of the word My?

Comment: Because the regex matches *the (one) character after a word boundary or `_`*. It does not match mid-word characters.

Comment: You could also do it the other way around: `strtolower` every character after `[A-Z]`. Look for *positive lookbehind* for more info.

Comment: Thanks - is the word boundary classed as the first character that defines a new word?

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex?

```
function camelize( $string ){

    return strtoupper( $string{0} ) . strtolower( substr( $string, 1 ) );

}

function camelizeClass( $class ){

    $parts = explode( '_', $class );
    array_walk( $parts, function( &$value, $key ){
        $value = camelize( $value );
    });
    return implode( '_', $parts );

}

echo camelizeClass( 'MY_NEW_CLASS' ); // My_New_Class
```

Comment: that's the excuse of lazy and bad programmers ... not a reason -jsut because you can write code in fewer lines if you don't use line-breaks doesn't mean you would/should do it

Comment: Lazy and bad programmers - I like it - cheers. You're right, it makes perfect sense to write two functions to do something that can be achieved using a single PHP function

Comment: yes, it does if it improves readability - who's gonna decypher in 2 months what the hell `/(?<=\b|_)./` is supposed to match after two other class naming schemas have been added and the regex is a complete mess

Comment: There's something to be said about directly expressing what you're trying to do though. A `preg_replace` that *matches every "first" character and uppercases it* is a lot more direct than exploding, looping, substringing and imploding. Also, more code = more *potential* for bugs. I agree in general with the sentiment of readability, but not all regexen are by default unreadable. It'd take me a lot longer to figure out what your 14 lines of code are doing than my one `preg_replace`. And you can always wrap it in a function with a self explanatory name and/or a comment.